# Facebook De-Authorization causes the api to fail

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So my issue is when I use the facebook api everything seems to work fine till I revoke permissions on the app. Once I do that the api stops working. Here is the code:

```
    if (socialMediaType == "facebook") {
      //it always gets to this location even after the revoke happens
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
         //gets in here fine on page load and other instances, 
         //but if you hit permissions delete it never gets here
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
        if (!ConnectButtonClicked) {
           FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", $scope.fbRevokeCallBack);
        } else { /*code here works fine*/ }
          } else {
         $scope.facebookLogin();
          }
        });
     }
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly with revoking permissions to the app?

Here is the call back:

```
    scope.fbRevokeCallBack = function (Data) {
            console.log('auth revoke', Data);
            // check for a valid response
            if (!Data || Data.error) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.fb.connectionError = true;
                    $scope.socialError = "error";
                });
                return;
            }
            if (Data) {
                console.log("Success");
            };
        }
```

Success is hit and the app is revoked as expected, but when you go back to reconnect to facebook the api does nothing. No calls can be found in the networking tab and the call back is never hit.

Some information:
This is using the Facebook JSSDK
and this is used in AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Would $scope.$apply() help here?

```
if (socialMediaType == "facebook") {
      //it always gets to this location even after the revoke happens
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
         //gets in here fine on page load and other instances, 
         //but if you hit permissions delete it never gets here
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
        if (!ConnectButtonClicked) {
           FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", $scope.fbRevokeCallBack);
        } else { /*code here works fine*/ }
          } else {
         $scope.facebookLogin();
          }
         $scope.$apply();
        });
     }
```

Comment: No this didn't help solve the issue. It actually causes a bunch of Angular errors that said "Error: $apply already in progress" - but ignoring that error it still didn't solve the issue. I tried it in the call back from the revoke as well and that didn't work either. It didn't do anything there.

Comment: Ok- thought the callback was not updating the Angular model. Here's the $scope.$apply() command that will avoid those errors, if you ever need it: $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();

Comment: Now when you say not updating the Angular model do you mean loosing the click event? Because the click even still fires as expected, it just when it get to the FB.getLoginStatus part that it fails. It gets to that line but never passes it. Like something is wrong within FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: If that is the case, sorry can't help you.. best of luck